# What's the difference between Zend Optimizer and Zend Guard Loader? And what do they actually do?

Tags: php, zend-optimizer, zend-guard

I've got an app which requires Zend Optimizer to run because it's encoded somehow. Search for Zend Optimizer at official Zend site leades to Zend Guard Loader. What's the difference between these programs? Is there a way to install one of them via APT in Ubuntu or via PEAR or something? And does one of them exclude using php 5.5?

Comment: Zend Optimizer+ was renamed to Zend Opcache mid of March 2013. as its name implies its a cache\optimiser not to be confused with Guard which is an encoder

Comment: It's written that I need a Zend Optimizer to run this CMS because it's somehow encoded. When I run it I see some code in a wrong encoding which is automatically reloded. Should it be enough to have Zend Opcache to run such applications encoded with Zend?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Zend Optimizer+ / Zend OPcache source [README](https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus):

> The Zend OPcache provides faster PHP execution through opcode caching and
>   optimization. It improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script
>   bytecode in the shared memory. This eliminates the stages of reading code from
>   the disk and compiling it on future access. In addition, it applies a few
>   bytecode optimization patterns that make code execution faster.

From the Zend Guard [download page](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/downloads):

> Zend Guard Loader is a free application that runs the files encoded using Zend Guard and enhances the overall performance of your PHP applications.

Zend Guard Loader only works with PHP 5.3 and 5.4. Prior to PHP 5.3 the runtime decoding [was a part of the Zend Optimizer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/system-requirements). Starting with PHP 5.3 the decoding capabilities were split out of the Optimizer and into the Guard Loader.

Zend Guard does not appear to currently support PHP 5.5.

Comment: What is Zend Optimizer itself without Zend Guard Loader? Is it a previous version of Zend Optimizer+?

Comment: Zend Optimizer+ was renamed into Zend OPcache in March 2013 (https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/commit/63cb63cf9610401c72170778dece798dd239b6d1). I don't know for sure but it looks like Zend Optimizer became Zend Optimizer+ when Zend Guard Loader was split out.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the execution of the Loader didn't show any speed- improvement to me..

Zend Loader scrambles a php file making it unreadable, and binds you to use the same PHP version number as when it was creating the encoded files, meaning you cannot upgrade from php 5.3 to 5.4 without re-encoding all your php files, which is a real pain if you do not have access to the original .php files.

packages that have files encoded are not anymore Open-source and make you dependent on their creator/developer, be aware that your server may not be upgraded unless your application is upgraded.